# Multidimensional array difference in php

Tags: php, cakephp

I have two arrays $a and $b.

```
$a = Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [a] => 1
                [d] => CONTACT
                [f] => 2
            )

    )
and
    $b = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [a] => 1
            [b] => 1
            [c] => 4
            [d] => CONTACT
            [e] => 2012-08-07  05:56:18
            [f] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [a] => 2
            [b] => 3
            [c] => 4
            [d] => CONTACT
            [e] => 2012-08-07  05:56:18
            [f] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [a] => 2
            [b] => 4
            [c] => 4
            [d] => CONTACT
            [e] => 2012-08-07  05:56:18
            [f] => 1
        )


)
```

if the  a,d,f field of first array match with second array , I want to delete the parent array of second array. in this case 
i want to do `unset($b[0]);`.How can i do this without loop? if can't, give me a solution with loop.Is there any method in cakephp?

Comment: First array has `a, d, f` keys. Can you clarify?

Comment: Why do you not want to use a loop?

Comment: array may contain 500 rows.I think loop will consume lot of processing power

Comment: So the array is dynamic. In that case, I don't think there is any other way (maybe I'm wrong?) apart from using a loop.

Comment: ok. please give me a loop solution

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$count = count($b)
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
{
    foreach($a[0] as $c => $v)
    {
        $match = true;
        if($b[$i][$c] != $v)
        {
            $match = false;
        }
        if($match)
            unset($b[$i]);
    }

}
```

that possibly could do the trick, but I guess there will be some kind of much faster way...
But I dont think 500 rows should be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this without a loop, but it won't be time consuming. Try this:

```
foreach ($b as $key => $value) {
    if (sizeof(array_diff_assoc($a[0], $value)) > 0) {
        unset($b[$key]);
    }
}
```